# C#/MySQL - How to fix this exception message: "You have an error in your SQL syntax"?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have the following method that inserts a new clothing item into a MySQL database in the table 'clothes'.

I'm getting the following exception message:

> Error: Actor.AddCloth() - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'CONDITION, WET_CONDITION, REPUTATION_BONUS,
>   ICON_ID) VALUES (12, 'Tunic', 11, 2,' at line 1

What I have done so far:

1. Check spelling - all correct
2. Check parameters - all seem okay
3. Check order - all correct
4. Checked syntax and spacing - seems to be correct
5. Checked the manual - nothing pops out at me

Thus, I'm lost on what's not working here. I use the same syntax for other methods and they are working fine.

Updated code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Inserts an actor's cloth state into the database.
/// </summary> 
/// <param name="clothItem">The cloth object to insert.</param>
/// <param name="actorID">The actor's ID.</param>
/// <returns>Returns true on success, else false.</returns>
public bool AddCloth(Cloth clothItem, long actorID)
{
    MySqlConnection conn;
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    int rows_affected = -1;

    try
    {
        // Open a connection
        conn = new MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = GlobalConstants.CONNECTION_STRING;
        conn.Open();

        // Query
        query.Clear();
        query.Append("INSERT INTO clothes (ACTOR_ID, CLOTH_NAME, TYPE_ID, BODY_SLOT_ID, MATERIAL_ID, COLOR_ID, ");
        query.Append("SMELL_ID, ENCHANTMENT_ID, WEIGHT, CLOTH_VALUE, CONDITION, WET_CONDITION, REPUTATION_BONUS, ICON_ID) ");
        query.Append("VALUES (@actor_id, @cloth_name, @type_id, @body_slot_id, @material_id, @color_id, ");
        query.Append("@smell_id, @enchantment_id, @weight, @cloth_value, @condition, @wet_condition, @reputation_bonus, @icon_id); ");

        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query.ToString(), conn);

        // Parameters
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("actor_id", actorID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cloth_name", clothItem.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("type_id", Convert.ToInt32(clothItem.Type)); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("body_slot_id", Convert.ToInt32(clothItem.BodySlot));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("material_id", Convert.ToInt32(clothItem.Material));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("color_id", Convert.ToInt32(clothItem.Color));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("smell_id", Convert.ToInt32(clothItem.Smell));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("enchantment_id", clothItem.EnchantmentID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("weight", clothItem.Weight);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cloth_value", clothItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("condition", clothItem.Condition);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("wet_condition", clothItem.WetCondition);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("reputation_bonus", clothItem.ReputationBonus);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("icon_id", clothItem.IconID); 

        // Execute query
        rows_affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Store the last inserted id as the cloth's id
        clothItem.ID = cmd.LastInsertedId;

        // Close connection
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Actor.AddCloth() - " + e.Message);
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Actor.AddCloth() - " + e.Message);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is `Value` a keyword in MySQL? edit: Looks like it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-V

Comment: Interesting find. However, I updated the script/db with 'cloth_value' instead of 'value', and I'm getting the same exception message.

Comment: I noticed 'name' is also a reserved word. Changing it and will see.

Comment: Changed name to cloth_name, but still same message. Updating script above.

Comment: Rather than changing all the column names individually, simply wrap them in identifiers.

Comment: Also note, `CONDITION` is an *unusable word for a column name* in MySQL (refer to link above).

Comment: It hates all of my chosen words haha. I'll update it and see real quick.

Comment: Success. Thanks, Jacob and all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your column name's is `VALUE`, right before MySQL indicates there is a syntax problem, which [is a reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in MySQL. You need to enclose it in backticks to properly escape it.

```
query.Append("SMELL_ID, ENCHANTMENT_ID, WEIGHT, `VALUE`, CONDITION, WET_CONDITION...
```

Comment: I changed it from value to cloth_value, and I'm still getting the same exception message.

Comment: Upon further conversation, there were three reserved words I was using. This was one of them.